# Is a CREATE FUNCTION required to define local variables for a SELECT statement using Postgres

Tags: plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

I am new to PostgreSQL and I'm trying to convert SELECT statements used in our application from an older version.  In doing so I have about 300 lines of SQL code on my first SQL SELECT statement where there are numerous local variables defined that are generally populated from a PHP front-end.  In trying to convert the code I'm wanting to define the LOCAL variables at the beginning of my code and just pass on the values that way.  I'm getting numerous errors from PostgreSQL.  Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

The 1st error is:

```
 Error: SQL Error: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$ DECLARE SYEAR numeric" LINE 3: DO $$ ^ Query: DO $$ DECLARE SYEAR numeric Error Info: Array ( [0] => 42601 [1] => 7 [2] => ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$ DECLARE SYEAR numeric" LINE 3: DO $$ ^ )
```

The second error is:

```
 Error: SQL Error: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "START_DATE" LINE 2: START_DATE date ^ Query: START_DATE date Error Info: Array ( [0] => 42601 [1] => 7 [2] => ERROR: syntax error at or near "START_DATE" LINE 2: START_DATE date ^ )
```

Here is my SQL code that I'm trying:

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE 
SYEAR numeric;  
START_DATE date;
END_DATE date; 
SCHOOL_ID numeric; 

BEGIN
    SYEAR := 2015;
    START_DATE := '2015-08-01';
    END_DATE := '2015-12-31';
    SCHOOL_ID := 002;

WITH main AS (
SELECT 
    s.student_id::TEXT, 
    s.last_name || ', ' || s.first_name as student, 
    dailyVisitTotal.count as Number_of_visits,
    dailyVisitTotal.duration_total as Daily_Visit_Total,
    firstAid.count as First_Aid_Visits,
    firstAid.duration_total as First_Aid_Total,
    majorAcc.count as Major_Accident_Visits,
    majorAcc.duration_total as Major_Accident_Total,
    illness.count as Illness_Visits,
    illness.duration_total as Illness_Total,
    medicationAdminTotal.count as Medication_Administration_Visits,
    medicationAdminTotal.duration_total as Medication_Administration_Total,
    specTotal.count as Specialization_Visits,
    specTotal.duration_total as Specialization_Total, 
    diabeticTotal.count as Diabetic_Visits,
    diabeticTotal.duration_total as Diabetic_Total

FROM students s 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        sle.student_id, 
        count(sle.*), 
        sum(coalesce(log_field20::numeric, 0)) || ' min' as duration_total 
    FROM student_log_entries_ml sle 
    INNER JOIN student_enrollment se 
        ON (sle.student_id=se.student_id and se.custom_9 is null 
        AND se.syear={SYEAR} 
        AND se.end_date is null)
    INNER JOIN schools sc on (se.school_id=sc.id) 
    WHERE student_field_id = 400000941
        AND log_field2::date between '{START_DATE}' and '{END_DATE}'  
        AND (log_field20 ~ '^[0-9]+$' or log_field20 is null) {SCHOOL_SPECIFIC} 
        AND se.school_id = {SCHOOL_ID}
    GROUP BY sle.student_id
) dailyVisitTotal 
ON (s.student_id = dailyVisitTotal.student_id))
END $$;
```

Comment: The first error tells you that you are missing a matching `$$` after the SQL statement. The second error tells you that the assignment statements after the `begin` are missing a `;` to end them (and it's better to use `:=` for assignment). Once you get around those syntax errors you will find out that you can't run a SQL statement in a PL/pgSQL function without storing the result somewhere.

Comment: And the CTE is missing the outer *main* query. Syntax nonsense even without plpgsql wrapper.